# How to check prisma server is running or not using mocha chai?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, supertest, prisma

after running `docker-compose up` Prisma server is running on port 4466.
I want to write a test case, which will check if it is running or not.

how can I achieve this?

so far, I have tried this

```
const url = "http://localhost:4466";

const request = require("supertest")(url);

  it("check if prisma server is open or not", done => {
    request
      .get("/")
      .expect(400)
      .end((err, res) => done());
  });
```

but it always passed the test. no matter status code 200 or 400.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want it for a test actually or you want to make sure that `Prisma` is running before any other service starts. In that case, I would suggest using [wait-port](https://github.com/dwmkerr/wait-port) in the `docker-compose` file.

Here is an example:

You want to deploy your backend after port `4466` is available.
You can do this with `wait-port`

```sh
wait-port 4466 && yarn deploy
```